# Using xargs and kill command

Tags: bash

I have a shell script that looks like this " pgrep 'process' | xargs kill -9 "
but if the 'process' does not exist, the kill command will complain that there is no input.
my question is: is there a way to exit from the code cleanly if there is no process to kill?
something like 'if pgrep return 0' run something else.
some kind of try, except in bash script.

Comment: Why not use `pkill`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gnu `xargs`, you can use the `-r` flag to avoid executing `kill` if there are no processes. However, the simplest solution is to use `pgrep`'s cousin, `pkill`, which was designed for this very purpose.